# Finding Rows by Column Values

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim foundRows() As Data.DataRow
foundRows = DataSet1.Tables("Customers").Select("CompanyName Like 'A%'")
```

I didn't try this code,if I try this how can I get the answer to msgbox...?? Or textbox

Comment: It maybe worth trying the code, then ask if it doesn't work

Comment: I think Its working.I cannot see any error messages.I should know how to get the answer to msgbox...?? Or textbox...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through the results and show them - for example :

```
For Each dr As DataRow In foundRows
  'Output to Textbox
  Textbox1.text &= dr("CompanyName").ToString
Next
```

Comment: One more question,now I need to replace A% as system.datetime.today, like this : foundRows = DataSet1.Tables("Customers").Select("CompanyName = 'system.datetime.today' '")   it doesn't work,,will you help me please...!!!